# How to use absolute value in Loopcut and edge slide?

Tags: modeling, edges

I want to make for example edge slide by 0.5 unit. How can I achieve this ? I don't want to use in edge slide fraction (from -1 to 1), instead real slide value.
I found that in previous versions of Blender there was in Edge Loop Proportional option, but I can't find it in newest Blender :/

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Outdated/Release_Notes/Modeling/Meshes/Advanced_Tools

From old manual:

*Pressing P while positioning the loop cut will enter non-proportional mode, which keeps the shape of one end of the faceloop regardless of where the cut is positioned. Pressing F while in non-proportional mode flips which side of the faceloop is used to determine the shape of the cut.*

[image]

Maya have this, Absolute Value.
http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Edit-Mesh--Slide-Edge-Tool-htm.html

Comment: Please place 1 or more images in the question to help others to understand your question.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in blender.

Comment: Isn't proportional now called **even** mode? E to enable it. If it doesn't behave like in maya it should be relatively straight forward to write a script.

Comment: My understanding of even is that each vertex is the same distance from one of the adjoining edge loops.  It is not 100% clear to me why slide is necessary here, though the initial placement of loop cut may be a problem.  In the image above one cannot see the edge loops to see the possible effects.  A more contained image would be better.  The lines are cut off on the view window.

Answer (score 7):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> you actually perform two actions: *Loop Cut* + *Edge Slide*.

The easiest way to slide edges a certain distance from a vertex is to slide to a vertex first, then slide the desired distance.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the ring to cut
2. <kbd>1</kbd> (or <kbd>-1</kbd>) to place the loop at the very last vertex of the edge you are cutting
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + *Edge Slide* + **relative distance**

### NOTE

In this way you can set *zero* at a vertex instead at the center.

It helps to calculate the absolute distance (as Carlo suggests), but actually doesn't allow to set edge slide by unit.

**You don't need to calculate the value manually: use Python expressions instead, simply typing <kbd>=</kbd> followed by the operation**

Check Edge Info: Length in Property Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>)

[image]

#### Even off

If you're sliding proportionally (Even off), you have to choose the edge wich the absolute slide amount refers to.

In this example, I want the edge to slide 0.5 units along the shortest edge.
[image]

Now the tricky part: type this simple operation (thanks @Carlo):

```
= absolute_distance / edge_lenght
```

in my case:

`= 0.5 / 1.13`

[image]

#### Even on

From [Blender Manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-slide)

> **Even E**
>
> Forces the edge loop to match the shape of the adjacent edge loop. You can flip to the opposite vertex using F. Use Alt-Wheel to change the control edge.
>
> **Flip F**
>
> When Even mode is active, this flips between the two adjacent edge loops the active edge loop will match

In this case, the operation is a bit longer, because *zero* is at the median point of the edge :

```
  = absolute_distance / edge_lenght - edge_lenght / 2
```

in my case:

`= 0.5 / 1.13 - 1.13 / 2`

[image]

**note:**

You'll notice a rounding error (the value is not exactly 0.5), because some approximation

Comment: Edge slide takes only a Factor (-1 to 1) as imput, not a "absolute distance". While this method make math operation easier (Factor=Absolute Distance/Edge lenght), I don't think that the problem can be marked as solved.

Comment: @Carlo you're right! Since the edges can have different lenghts, Blender use Percentage values to proportionally slide despite the different lenghts. To make math operations, one ought to indicate an edge as reference.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

In the above image a loop cut was made ... moved to one extreme side ... then a simple grab was performed in the global X .5 direction.  Length is enabled to show the edge in question.

If the loop is lined up with the global XYZ axis you can type

Keyboard GX1 ... Grab Move in the X axis 1 unit.

If the loop should be moved in the local coordinate axis you can type

Keyboard GXX1 ... Grab Move in the local X axis 1 unit

Loops were created at a relative zero location and moved by G [Grab] only.

You can consider creating an orientation as well.

[image]

Using the orientation based on a face orientation Y .75 units

Local axis still aligned with global axis.

GYY .75

[image]