# How can I edge slide to an accurate value on one axis?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I want to slide this edge to 38.4cm on the Z axis. The only way I know how to slide edges is double tapping G and sliding it with the mouse, which is not accurate enough for my needs.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way for me to type in a specific global value without messing up the right side of the mesh?

Comment: I deleted my answer. Not easy, but maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38955/how-to-use-absolute-value-in-loopcut-and-edge-slide

Comment: I got this to work, but it's prone to interpolation errors.

1) Add a loop cut in the center

2) Calculate the distance you need to move.
For me only the Z axis was relevant, so I tooke the end point o=400 and the starting point (lower edge of the mesh) a=96 and got the length by calculating the difference (l=o-a=304). I wanted the cut to be z-16 from the top, so I needed to move by 288 from the bottom. 288/304 gives me a factor, but because I halved the distance by cutting in the middle I need to double the difference this ratio has to 1.

3) Press GG enter the ratio and pray to interp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, previously added a completely wrong answer...

After some struggling I agree that is a shame that you can't set a precise sliding end position (at least on global axes) or at least snap to some other vertex or edge... this should be fixed, imho (although it is not currently considered a bug... https://developer.blender.org/T41346).

I have another workaround, not very much elegant but at least you could try this, too, at least this is what I tried:

First I duplicated this edge:

[image]

then, I selected those edges, whose Z value was 0.00, and grabbed (not slided) them to a precise value (0.2 in my example)

[image]

of course ending with this wrong result, though you can see the duplicated edge I created before, as a "reference" that keeps the correct slope angle...

[image]

then, tried to correct the wrong vertex position (only one in this case), after activating snap to edges

[image]

I then grabbed (locking on X axis) until the vertex snapped to the "reference" edge)

[image]

Finally, I had to delete the "reference" slope edge

[image]

here you see the "real" edge selected after removing the "reference" one

[image]

That's it, I hope at least this gives you an alternative...

Comment: Because if there isn't some fancy option I don't know about yet it messes with the mesh like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ByeP5om.png)

Comment: I've just modified and then restored my previous answer, not sure if it will answer you, it's more a workaround, but still...

Comment: This is still a lot of struggle, but it's a whole lot more practical than what I did creating a plane and intersecting it. Thanks a lot! I think this is the closest to a decent solution we will get.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Sometimes you need to type <kbd>-</kbd> (negative) to invert the direction of the movement.

Comment: I tried this before and it doesn't work. Maybe my settings are off, but this moves the edge somewhere completely off. Here is what happens for me: ![screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8b7wmJy.png)

Comment: Maybe you'll have to apply the scale of your object first (ctrl A). If the object hasn't a scale of 1.1.1 all measures get deformed.

Comment: Just tried applying the scale - same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know the height before and devide it with distance you want to move.
In example lets say height is 2.9m. So type "gg=0.384/2.9"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a plane, moving it to the desired Z-coordinate and intersecting the meshes, but I am still very much interested in alternative solutions, as this is obviously not always a feasible solution.