# How to slide a edge by 10cm increments?

Tags: edges

I made a loop cut, slided it first all the way to the top, then slid it down and got 10 cm away from the top, which is good. I've tried to do the same thing for the bottom edge loop (to try to slide it 10cm away from the bottom) and it snaps to 9,5cm instead of 10cm. The only way I could fix this is by turning incrementing off, but is there something I can press to keep incrementing on?

Why does the second loop even increment to 9,5cm, instead of 10cm like the first one?

[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91217/how-can-i-edge-slide-to-an-accurate-value-on-one-axis/91224#91224

Answer (score 1):

Edge Slide and loop cuts go by a “factor”, not a distance. So the snapping constrains that factor--in my quick test, to multiples of 0.1.

In your case you can select all the points and type in the exact value for the Z-coordinate that you want. This might be the easiest way.